# Possible automated Bing Ads fraud?

Tags: spam, bing, fraud-detection

I run a website that generates life insurance leads.  The site is very simple a) there is a form for capturing the user's details, life insurance requirements etc b) A quote comparison feature

We drive traffic to our site using conventional Google Adwords and Bing Ads campaigns.

Since the 6th January we have received 30-40 dodgy leads which have the following in common:

1. All created between 2 and 8 AM
2. Phone number always in the format "123 1234 1234'
3. Name, Date Of Birth, Policy details, Address all seem valid and are unique across the leads
4. Email addresses from "disposable" email accounts including dodgit.com, mailinator.com, trashymail.com, pookmail.com
5. Some leads come from the customer form, some via the quote comparison feature
6. All come from different IP addresses
7. We get the keyword information passed through from the URLs
8. All look to be coming from Bing Ads
9. All come from Internet Explorer v7 and v8

The consistency of the data and the random IP addresses seem to suggest an automated approach but I'm not sure of the intent.

We can handle identifying these leads within our database but is there anyway of stopping this at the Ad level i.e. before the click through.

Comment: We have several websites experiencing the same problem. We began noticing the above described spam coming through our online forms around December 23. Only recently, did I notice a correlation with these spams and some unusual Bing click activity--a very high impression to click to conversion ratio. I just reported our issue to Bing and hope to hear back from them.

Comment: I would report the clicks to Bing, you have no control of stopping the click fraud at the ad level. That can only be done by Bing. Though Google and i'm sure Bing don't charge you if someone has saved the destination URL from an Ad. Even so, contact Bing. You can also check the IP's against https://www.arin.net if a company owns them you'll get contact information. I'd also Google the IP's.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly being done by your competitors and they are using an automated bot, to empty your allocated adwords account balance.

You have to report the fraud clicks to Bing. [Report Here](http://advertise.bingads.microsoft.com/en-us/product-help/bingads/topic?market=en-us&project=adcenter_denver_wave2_std&query=moonshot_proc_reportinvalidclicks.htm)

From your side you can only report and expect Bing to act on it ( your issue seems to very conserning and must be treated with high priority). 
Even blocking the IPs will not work as bot is using  different IP each time.